# como colorir as caixinhas duma grid 3 por 2 em css

Tags: html, css, grid, flexbox, webdesign

Tenho o seguinte codigo em html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

e o meu css é:

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

```
.wrapper {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 200px 50px 100px;
grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
```

}

eu quero que cada caixinha tenha uma cor diferente

Comment: É só colocar um background-color para cada div... não deu para entender exatamente o seu problema...

Comment: será que cada div tem que ter uma class?

Comment: pode ser por classe ou colocando um style direto na tag da div. crie classes de com, tipo .red {background-color: red}, assim vc pode usar class="red" em todos os elementos que quiser essa cor, faz o mesmo para as outras 5 cores que vai precisar e pronto, não tem mistério. Sua pergunta não está clara, não explica direito como quer as cores, quais as limitações ou regras etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sem modificar o HTML, você pode usar `:nth-child` e adicionar estilo de acordo com a posição entre "irmãos".

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 50px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(1) { background: red }
.wrapper div:nth-child(2) { background: green }
.wrapper div:nth-child(3) { background: blue }
.wrapper div:nth-child(4) { background: yellow }
.wrapper div:nth-child(5) { background: cyan }
.wrapper div:nth-child(6) { background: orange }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```